# Opening LaTeX file

Tags: errors

I open any LaTeX file, but LaTeX sees it as one file which am not opening. When I run the manuscript it gives only one result even opening other LaTeX files. What could be wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! When LaTeX opens a file you wrote it does so to read it. Probably you mean a LaTeX editor, but you give us no idea which it might be, which OS you're running and which TeX distribution. As it is currently written this question is far too broad to get an answer.

Comment: Which editor are you using?  It looks as though one file has been tagged as the `master file.'

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: If you are using for example TeXstudio, you should look in the menu under 'Options/Root document/'. You should also check if the file you are trying to compile has no magic-comment defining another document as root. You should look for `% !TeX root =` in your document and remove this comment where necessary.